# built-in "all()" function for dictionary values (not keys)

Tags: python, dictionary

Is there a built-in function that could compare the values of a dictionary, like the built-in `all()` function can compare a list or tuple for example and return `True` or `False` + the dictionary key that it was from?

What I want to achieve, is to give the `all()` function a dictionary rather than a list. The default behaviour for `all()` would be to return `True` if there is an element missing or that is falsey:

```
>>> all([1,2,3,4,0])
False
>>> all(['hello', 'world', ''])
False
>>> all(['hello', 'world', None])
False
>>> all([1,2,3,4])
True
>>> all(['hello', 'world'])
True
```

With the vanilla `all()` function, it only returns the `True` of `False` value, which is fine for comparison if I want to check these booleans. However, I cannot then know which of the values were  falsey, in order to tell the user why there was a problem.

I have created a function which will just that. In addition to a boolean, it returns the element's key for which the value was falsey:

```
# dictionary all function (working with 3.x)
def dict_all(iterable):
    for key in iterable:
        if not iterable[key]:
            return False, key
    return True
```

I want it to exit early, we don't need to test all values.

Is there a built-in function that does this? If not, why not? It seems like it would be useful in all sorts of instances.

I'm using this for a function where each of the keyword arguments have a default value of `None`, to supply a default for when the user does not set a value. I use  `dict_all()` function provide an error message when `False, key` is returned.

For example:

```
dictionary = {'jira_key' : 'REDACTED',
    'summary' : 'this is a test',
    'desc' : 'this is a description',
    'req_type' : 'PMV',
    'comp_type' : None}
```

Expected outcome is return `False, 'comp_type'`

Also for those refuting the usefulness of the `True` and `False` being returned as a Tuple, I give you this example:

```
>>> example = dict_all(iterable)
#if iterable is the example dictionary above
#the result would be
>>> print(example)
(False, 'comp_type')
#which means
#example[0] is a Truthy or Falsey for the value in the key
#they key is example[1]
```

Comment: what about `all(my_dict.values())` ?

Comment: You edited your `dict_all` function to do something different. Which one are you using? Should I delete my answer?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I had not considered that. I will give it a whirl and get back to you :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: that won't work because each `(key, value)` tuple is true, and `all()` still will only produce a yes or no answer, not the answer to this different question, which is "what is the first key that fails to meet the criteria set".

Comment: @Swift: no need, what Jean-François proposes can't work.

Comment: so this isn't really an `all` function you want. `all` returns a boolean. It's the old "I want to know the reason why it returned True or False" question. Do it with a custom method

Comment: No, I understand why it returns the true of false values, but as far as I'm concerned, all() will NOT work with dictionary values out of the box. all() will only work with the dictionary keys, hence why I am asking if there is a similar built-in function to the one that I have written to do the job.

Comment: Seems like you got what needed from @MartijnPieters (if so, it would be nice to accept his answer). I am not aware of a built in function that returns dict keys with falsy values. If you want to return all the dict keys with falsy values (rather than just the first one), you could do it very tersely with list comprehension: `[k for k, v in d.items() if not v]` where `d` is your dict. Similarly if you wanted to get all the key \ value pairs with falsy values, you could use dict comprehension: `{k:v for k, v in d.items() if not v}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is to iterate over the key-value *pairs* so you can test the value without having to refer back to the original mapping again, and return the key when the value is falsey. You also need to be *consistent in your return type*, and return a tuple in both cases:

```
def dict_all(mapping):
    for key, value in mapping.items():
        if not value:
            return False, key
    return True, None
```

Note the change on the last line, you really don't want to return a tuple for the false case, and a single boolean for the true case, because then you also have to test the return type before you can actually know what was missing.

There is no 'built-in' function for this because `all()` (and `any()`) are designed purely to produce a yes or no answer to the question: *do all elements of an iterable pass a test*.

You are asking something different; your code needs to know *what the first key is that fails to pass the test*.

For that question, I'd use the [`next()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next), with a generator expression and a default value:

```
empty = next((key for key, value in mapping.items() if not value), None)
if empty is not None:
    raise CustomException('Missing value for {}'.format(empty))
```

There is no need to return `True` or `False` here; we detect that there was no key that failed the test when the default case was picked, we replaced the `True` or `False` value with a test for `empty is not None`.

Any unique sentinel will do; `None` is the usual choice, but you could use `object()` if your input dictionary used `None` as a valid key:

```
_sentinel = object()
empty = next((key for key, value in mapping.items() if not value), _sentinel)
if empty is not _sentinel:
    raise CustomException('Missing value for {}'.format(empty))
```

Comment: I edited some of the scoped variables in the dict_all() function because you said I am not comparing the values, but that I'm checking for falsey keys, which I believe is a misunderstanding of the code.

Comment: Vanilla `all()` function would check for falsey keys

Comment: And also, please accept my thanks for your answer. I see the point your making but I think I made a mess of the question. Sorry Martijn :(

Comment: @Swift: it's okay, we got there in the end.

Comment: I like this `_sentinel` answer, I've not dived into custom errornhandlong much and that would be a very good use of my time to understand how that works. Thanks again Martijn. I will verify you answer works for purpose but it sounds like we have a weiner

Answer (score 1):

edit: This answer was written in the context of your original `dict_all` function before you edited it.

```
def dict_all(iterable):
    for i, e in enumerate(iterable):
        if not iterable[e]:
            return False, e
    return True
```

I have three remarks.

First, I'm not sure whether you are aware of it, so I'll point it out: your `dict_all` looks for falsy *values*, while a dictionary is an iterable over its keys.

```
>>> d = {1:2, 3:0}
>>> all(d)
True
>>> dict_all(d)
(False, 3)
```

Second, the `enumerate` in your function seems pointless. Consider the following generator expression.

```
>>> next(((False, key) for key, value in d.items() if not value), (True, None))
(False, 3)
>>> d = {1:2, 3:4}
>>> next(((False, key) for key, value in d.items() if not value), (True, None))
(True, None)
```

Third, wouldn't be getting the actual falsy value be more useful than just getting `False`? In that case use `(value, key)` instead of `(False, key)` in the expression above.

edit: since you asked for a library function, you could use `itertools.dropwhile` to drop dictionary items with truthy values.

```
>>> from itertools import dropwhile    
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> 
>>> d = {1:2, 3:4, 5:0}
>>> next((dropwhile(itemgetter(1), d.items())), None)
>>> (5, 0)
```

This will give you *a* (key, value) pair with a falsy value or `None`.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to comment on the other answer

Comment: @Swift your original `dict_all` looks for falsy values in the dict and then returns the key. `all` looks whether there is any falsy key in the dict.

Comment: I want the key from a falsey value. Sorry if that is not clear. If i just wanted falsey keys, then the builtin `all()` would work just fine :)

Comment: @Swift yes, your function does that. The generators do this, too. I just wanted to point out that your `dict_all` does not just behave like `all` plus returning the falsy value.

Comment: @Swift added mentioning `dropwhile` from `itertools`. You might find it useful for this task.

Comment: May I ask, how does it behave differently to the builtin all()? (Other than returning a tuple with a boolean and a key/None, in the event that it reutrns True)

Comment: @Swift `all` iterates over the **KEYS** of a dictionary and returns `False` when there is a falsy key. The custom functions/solutions here look for a falsy **VALUE**. Check out the the difference between `all` and `dict_all` in the second code block of my answer.

Comment: So with that in mind, if I were to update my current function so that it only checked for Falsey and Truthy values (not keys) but only returned the Truthy or Falsey then this would emulate the `all()` builtin but for the values in a dictionary instead of the default behaviour of checking the keys?

Comment: @Swift [This is starting to get ridiculous](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258279/3620003). Martijn and I explained to you how `all` works from a number of different angles already. It's now time to stop asking follow up questions and read the documentation if things still are unclear.